# How to access and update the fragment components (SeekBar, TextBox etc.) from MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a fragmented layout where I have two fragments FragmentA and FragmentB. FragmentA contains a seekbar i.e. seekBar1.

How can I set the progress of this seekbar (seekBar1.setProgress(68)) from MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

You can find your fragment from activity by :

```
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pageview)
```

or

```
YourFragment yourFragment = (YourFragment) = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pageview)
```

Also, you can use findFragmentByTag method.

than call the public function such as:

```
yourFragment.setSeekBarProgress(...)
```

Comment: Thankyou.... i found one more way i.e. i can directly access the views from the activity if i define them as static so, its like FragmentA.seekBar1.setProgress(68).

Comment: It means that those views will be available even if they are not appear. make sure you know what's you are doing :) good luck